# Reusing a View within a ListView row - "The specified child already has a parent" Exception

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-adapter

I have a ListView whose rows display data held within a `Message` Class. The view for each row is built when the `Message` Class is initialized and stored as a ViewGroup. I chose to do this as building the ViewGroup within the ListView adapters `getView` method was slow and caused the ListView to stutter when scrolled.

Ideally, in the ListView adapter I want to get a reference to the rows root view (which is a FrameLayout) and add this ViewGroup to it I.e. `rootView.addView(message.getBody())` where getBody() returns the ViewGroup stored in the message class.

However if I do this I get this exception when I scroll up and down the list a few times:

```
IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent
```

If I attempt to call `removeAllViews()` on the rows root view the outcome is the same.

Is there a way to build a view once, store it within an object and simply add this to a row over and over?

Thanks

Comment: Try to to help yourself with the use of a collection, where You store the desired combinations. Until now Your logic is exposed to java runtime and there this multiple assignment is forbidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` is caching `View`s, so when you do this:

```
rootView.addView(message.getBody());
```

you may be trying to add a view that is already added to another of the `ListView`s cached `View`s. You should be able to fix this by explicitly removing the `View` from its parent `ViewGroup` before you add it to the root view:

```
ViewGroup vg = message.getBody();
ViewParent parent = vg.getParent();
if (parent != null && parent instanceOf ViewGroup) {
    // if this ViewGroup already has a parent, unlink it from that parent
    //  before adding it to the new one 
    ((ViewGroup)parent).removeView(vg);
}
rootView.addView(vg);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter class you can check for convertView being null in `getView(...)`.  For example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row_layout, null);

    //Your other work here

    return convertView;
}
```

The convertView allows for re-use of the cell which is what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't think this will help. I am currently using the convertView to recycle the row layout. The issue is removing the message view group from the last view it was added to.